# How to select and save multiple ids in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im building a site where a business can create staff and competences.
The business first creates the staff. After that when creating the competences they should choose which staff who has that competence.
I have a working solution where i save the staff ids in an array which belongs_to clinic. 
I would like to have a connection between the models so i can call both Business.staff.competences and Business.competence.staffs.

Answer (score 0):

bsh,

It sounds like you need to have many to many association between competence and staff.  Here is a link to Rails guide which talks about how to set it up.  Look at section 2.4 that has what you want to accomplish.

[has_many :through Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)